# informatica power center memory usage

Tags: etl, informatica-powercenter

I try to understood how to optimize all workflows.
I'm in stuck on finding a solution.
I see that sometimes Informatica Power Center is using a lot of space. For this reason I've got some data leak.
I tried to see the settings in the session configuration, but it didn't solve the problem. Could anyone tell me if it's possible to limit the use of available memory?
The problem subsists that in some cases much more data arrives and consequently there is a lack of resources to be able to process everything.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a informatica ETL system where sometime lot of data arrives and your system crashes or not able to process all, first thing is -

1. Identify which workflows are taking time in such scenario. Which workflow processes more data. Tune them if you can - Use partitions/multiple sessions if you can.
2. Set default buffer block size, DTM buffer size to Auto so informatica handles them internally. Change them if you know your requirement. Keep them Automatic Memory Limits as is.

Still, if your issue persists, I think you need to take a look into system configurations -

1. Check if system has minimum recommended Space, Ram and CPU. A prod machine should have 32GB disk, 4 vcore cpu, 8GB Ram minimum.
2. Number of concurrent sessions. This is an important settings in integration service. Reduce this to 5 and see how your system behaves (Default is 10).
   Log into Admin Console> Select the node on which the Integration Service is running> properties >In Resource Provision Threshold change the value of the Maximum Processes.
3. If you have concurrent workflows settings turned on, see if you can tune it / change it to reduce memory usage.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I didn't solve the problem. I see that it used just 16% of memory. But it uses a lot of swapped space and then fails.

Comment: which means it doesnt have plenty of RAM. What is your RAM size ? And also, when you see swap is getting captured, how many sessions are running - and how many GB of data are they processing. Its also possible infa is caching very large tables and capturing cache space. But since you mentioned swap space i am not considering lookup/aggregator/sorter cache.

Comment: I have 64gb of memory. And now I observed that I've got 18% of memory usage and 39% of cached. So all cached data goes to swap.

Comment: cache is used for Sorter/Aggregator/Lkp. So, pls monitor swap space for a whole day and see which session is capturing it.